# mysqli_fetch_array php to rertieve value from DB

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Im trying to retrieve a password from a database using mysqli_fetch_array and save it into a variable in order to be used later. but i got no value when i tried to echo it.

Thats what i did

```
$select=mysqli_query($con,"select L2 from login where L1='$usrname'");
$fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($select,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$datapassword= $fetch['L2']; 

echo "$datapassword<br>$oldpassword<br>$newpassword<br>$confirmpassword";
```

Give me ideas please !!

Comment: Idea - use `var_dump` and see what vars you have

Comment: Basic debugging is in order. Did you verify that your query executed successfully?  `var_dump($select); echo mysqli_error($con);`